Sorting columns with POM in Playwright Typescript not working
I want to fetch column1, column2,ect.. values and sort the column accordingly. Below is the HTML structure. Im unable to locate and fetch the column values.
When Im running the below code, Im getting empty list in 'allValues'. Please help me where I made a mistake.
my html
    <div role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1">
     <div> value 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1">
     <div> value 2 </div>
    </div>
<!-- More rows... -->
   

my test file
  test("sorting columns data", async ({ page }) => {

  const sortColumn = new SortColumns(page, "1");
  const columnValues = await sortColumn.getColumnValues();
  console.log(columnValues);
  const sortedNames = [...columnValues].sort();
  expect(columnValues).toEqual(sortedNames);

});

sort-columns.ts file
import { type Locator, type Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class SortColumns {
 columnValue: Locator;
 page: Page;

 constructor( page: Page,  element: string ) {

   this.page = page;
   this.columnValue =  page.locator(`[role=aria-colindex]`, { hasText: element });
   console.log("test: "+this.columnValue);

 }

async getColumnValues() {
  const allValues = await this.columnValue.allInnerTexts();
  console.log(allValues);
  return allValues.slice(1); // Remove header
}

}


This seems like a misapplication of a POM, since SortColumns isn't a page. Each POM should be, say, Landing, Dashboard, TweetDetail, etc, and encapsulate all locators to manipulate that page. this.columnValue.allInnerTexts(); should not be used because it's not a web-first assertion. Use await expect(loc).toHaveText(["value 1", "value 2"]) instead. Ideally, modify your locator rather than using .slice(), or use expect.any() to skip the header in the assertion.

First, aria-colindex is not a role. And second, hasText is not applied to the column you used in the locator. It's used to filter the text of the element.
You could do something like this:
const columns = page.locator(`[aria-colindex="${element}"]`);


In console, columnValues is coming empty. But in debug mode, values are coming. What could be the issue here? @hardkoded

@naveen are you awaiting the statement?

resolved, thanks @VishalAggarwal
